# Cross-browser double border / inner outline

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

What is the proper way to re-create a subtle inner outline like the following that works  cross-browser?

[image: div double border]

Currently, I've an outer div and an inner div which both have a border of different color. Is there a solution that only uses one div and not two?

Comment: I'm assuming you can't use border-style:double because you wan't two different colors?

Comment: Correct, border-style:double just makes it look like a frame rather than creating the thin inner-border effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/meyvn/)***

What I usually do for this type of approach is make a div container with a border and a padding. And then I will have a div inner with a border. This way the container can hold the outer border and the contained border colors. And your inner div can hold the inner border color.

html

```
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">
    <div class="content">
        Just some text.<br>
        Could be other stuff,<hr>
        In here too.
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

css

```
body{
 background-color:#545454;
}
.outer{
 border: 2px solid black;
 padding: 3px;
 border-radius:4px;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 background-color:#858585;
}
.inner{
 background-color:#545454;
 width:196px;
 height:196px;
 border-radius:4px;
 border:2px solid black;
}
.content{
 color:white;
 padding:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested: You can use a combination of `box-shadow`, `outline` & `border`:

```
div{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:#F7F7F7;
    box-shadow:0 0 3px red inset;
    outline: solid 2px blue;
    border:solid 1px #F7F7F7;
}
```

Preview: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vthAJ

Answer (score 0):

You can try using CSS3 border images:

http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

This will allow you to just use one div.
You just need to create simple, small repeatable thumbnails. Just have one color on one side, another color on the other. Or create a gradient like in the picture. You probably know the drill.

I think if you combine it with CSS3 border-radius you can also get the rounded corners effect.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Jeuvy/1/)

You can add the `:after` psuedo-element with a border.

```
.double {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid silver;
}

.double:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot has border-radius as well, so if you can use CSS3 and are only looking to go a version back in IE there are CSS3 methods that will work using `box-shadow: inset...` to accomplish the second border.

If you are not concerned about the border-radius aspect of the screenshot you can use a combo of `border` and `outline`. Please see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxinacube/RyQbF/) for an example.